# How can I get a shovel?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I would really like to bury these peaches my mom sent so I can grow more peaches, but I don't have a shovel! I figure it's a DIY recipe, but do I have to do something specific to unlock it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shovels are essential for digging some fossils for Museum, so the best bet is to get Blathers:

1. Give five bugs or fish to Tom Nook at Residents' Services to get tent kit for Blathers;
2. Place Blathers's tent;
3. Visit Blathers to receive shovel recipe.

[Source 1](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/20/21185842/museum-unlock-blathers-fossils-fish-bugs), [Source 2](https://www.gamesradar.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-shovel/).

Comment: Source 1 & Source 2 are, now, the same site(?).

Comment: @user3306356 fixed! looks like you are the first one to open both links :)

Comment: What do I win? 

Comment: @user3306356 1 comment upvote, congratulations!

Comment: Wow! What an honor!